# Out of memory increment operator with strange syntax

Tags: coldfusion, garbage-collection, cfml, coldfusion-2018

This ColdFusion will compile and run. And later causes a GC Limit.

```
<cfset theCount = 0++>
```

**Results**

```
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"GC overhead limit exceeded","timeStamp":1570564484803,"path":null}
```

What is going on?

Ref: This code came from a comment on: [count total records for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292615/count-total-records-for-each-user)

Comment: Submitted bug: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4205375

Comment: Out of curiosity, how large was the list you were looping over?

Comment: I am not looping over anything. I looked at the code on other question, and I wondered if it would work. I got unexpected results.

Comment: If the code is meant to iterate, and it's not inside a finite loop, would it not stand to reason that it would just count up forever and crash the page? I don't understand why you'd just paste it anywhere and expect it to work. I'm having a brainfart.

Comment: I think I was confused. I think the code was intended to be pseudocode and it just happen to compile and run as is. I am thinking it is my misunderstanding and Adobe's bug.

Comment: Yeah, if I were actually creating something like that it'd have to be `<cfset theCount = 0>` and then inside the loop, `#theCount++#` - so it was actually my mistake for writing it that way. For what it's worth my CF2018 server acknowledges that it's a syntax error and it does not run. No GC message. So still a very interesting find.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much interesting in this. It is a run time bug, but it should have been a compile time error. Hopefully Adobe will fix it.